# Fetch result from two different tables and show as single result

Tags: sql

I have two tables named `document` and `levelnew`

Table1: document:

```
document(mno,dept,step1_userid,step2_userid,step3_userid)

select * from document where step3_userid is not null;
```

Table2: levelnew:

```
levelnew(dept,level2_id,level3_id)

select dept from levelnew where level3_id='40016022';
```

Can i join the tables and get answer as single result?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: Provide expected result aslo..

Comment: Here joining of 2 tables is done based on common dept column and two conditions are given : 1) level3_id 2) step3_userid

Comment: we have two tables(document, levelnew) which have common column named "department". i want to select everything from table 'document' where 'step3_userid is not null' and contain multiple department assign to the userid in levelnew table. i can get multiple department list with simple query 'select dept from levelnew where level3_id='40016022'; but how do i use this list to select from table document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a join on Dept.

```
select A.*,B.dept from document  A inner join levelnew B On
    A.dept = B.dept
    Where step3_userid is not null and level3_id='40016022'
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query will give the required result :-

```
select 
D.*,L.dept
from
document D
inner join
levelnew L on D.dept=L.dept
where L.level3_id='40016022' AND D.step3_userid is not null;
```